# Prevent uuid collision in Python same process

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

I am generating uuid in Python, I noticed there are collisions. I get collisions if I use `uuid.uuid1()` or `uuid.uuid4()`.

I read many articles online but they elaborate about the *"theory"* of impossibility of UUID collision if generated properly.

But I have yet to find one that explains how I can ensure my **UUID generation is properly done**.

How can I do this before `Python 3.7`?
I saw [Python 3.7 has a notion of UUID safety](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) but is there a way to do this outside of 3.7?

**Details:**
running on Ubuntu 18.04, running Python code in Jupyter Lab.

Comment: Use encapsulation, create a UUID factory object, where you save old ones in a set, then every time check is the new UUID exist or no, then return it only if it doesn't exist, else repeat.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of we need to understand how **UUID** is generated.

**UUID1** is generated depending on `time + Host ID + random component`. So if you generate **UUID1** on the **same host** at **the same time** you only rely on the `random component` which is 14 bits which means that you have 1 chance out of 16384 to have a collision. Not very high but should be considered.

**UUID4** is full random(128bits) and should NOT collide, if it's colliding in your case it's probably due to something on your system like on this [issue](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/80).

Could you please specify your os for further investigations ? 
Do you have os.urandom installed ?

Comment: hi @thomas-kostas I have added my OS and Python details. I am running it in Jupyter Lab, I am not sure if that could be the cause..

Comment: @cryanbhu do you use multiprocessing to generate those colliding UUIDs ? is os.urandom installed and working properly ?

Comment: i do not know multiprocessing and have no multiprocessing in my code. But I do have a `for` loop in my code in the Notebook. I have tried to reproduce the error but I don't get it today. I suspect Jupyter Notebook might do some _behind the scenes_ multiprocessing magic? I have no idea how it happened. It might have been fixed because I opened a new Jupyter server and Notebook today. Hope this helps others who might run into this in the future.

Comment: Glad to here that, I do not know much about Jupyter Lab to be honest but as you said it seems to be notebook dependent. Please mark the problem as solved.